# String display incorrectly when in codeigniter input value using the form helper

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a strange issue I never had before.
I have a record stored in my database, it is a dutch place name as follow:

's-Heer Abtskerke

if I use the form helper:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php
    echo form_label('Plaats','plaats');
    echo form_error('plaats');
    echo form_input('plaats',set_value('plaats',$object->plaats),'class="form-control" id="plaats"');
    ?>
</div>
```

I am getting this output:

```
&#039;s-Heer Abtskerke
```

And if I use the html input element:

```
<input type="text" name="plaats" class="form-control" id="plaats" value="<?php echo $object->plaats; ?>">
```

I get the correct output:

's-Heer Abtskerke

I am wondering what is going on in here!

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off html escape:

```
set_value('plaats','\'s-Heer Abtskerke', FALSE)
```

[Here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#set_value) you have doc